# What is an example of a callback defined as method on a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the Rails API docs I came across the following statement on the topic of [cancelling callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#module-ActiveRecord::Callbacks-label-Canceling+callbacks):

> Callbacks are generally run in the order they are defined, with the exception of **callbacks defined as methods on the model**, which are called last.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `callbacks defined as methods in the model` refers to overwriting callbacks in the model.

The [Inheritable callback queues](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html#module-ActiveRecord::Callbacks-label-Inheritable+callback+queues) section in the same page has the examples.

#### Example of a callback macro:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_destroy :destroy_author
end
```

#### Example of a callback method:

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  def before_destroy() destroy_author end
end
```

Any callback defined with a `def` would be called last.

Comment: Cool, thanks! Furthermore, as per the same docs, *use the callback macros when you want to ensure that a certain callback is called for the entire hierarchy, and use the regular overwritable methods when you want to leave it up to each descendant to decide whether they want to call super and trigger the inherited callbacks.*